# Loop over a WTForm class fields

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-wtforms

How do I loop over a WTForms all filled with in a class

What I have tested is just using the loop around it

Forms classes

```py
class someForm(FlaskForm):
     some_filled_one = StringField('some_filled_one')
     some_filled_two = StringField('some_filled_two')
     ...
```

then I have a anther place were I want to loop over this fields.

```py
dict = {"some_filled_one" : "some text", "some_filled_two" : "some text 2"}
form = someForm()
for key in dict.keys():
     response = request.form[key]
     ... #do some thing
```

this givs me an error :

```
werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError
werkzeug.exceptions.HTTPException.wrap.<locals>.newcls: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to comment on this, so I have do draw an answer.

First, why do you create a dictionary for looping through request.form? Everything is accessable with `request.form.keys()`. And without sending a request before, the object `request` won't exist. So, looping trough the form objects you could either use `request.form.keys()` combined with `request.form[key]` or `request.form.items()`

Secondly, my guess is that whatever happens after `#do some thing` might be wrong.

Regards, Thomas